# How to delete added value in cells in Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Now]

From the picture on the left side, it is the input and after the user presses the button the output will appear on the right side. 
My problem is that after the user presses the button and the result appears. I want the inputted data on the left side to disappear so that the user can re-input the data again and again

What do I need to add in my code so that it will give the result I want. 
This is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set AddNew = wks.Range("M65356").End(xlUp).Offset(5, 0)

For i = 1 To 15
    For j = 1 To 7
        AddNew.Cells(i, j) = wks.Range("B1").Cells(i, j)
    Next j
Next i




End Sub
```

Comment: Your current code skips the last line of input. Plus you don't need to run two loops to copy a range over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add :

```
wks.Range("B1").Cells(i, j) = ""
```

After your AddNew line

Answer (score 0):

Your current code skips over the last inputline (15). But maybe consider to not use loops but to transfer the data in one go:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wks As Worksheet: Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim AddNew As Range: Set AddNew = wks.Range("M65356").End(xlUp).Offset(5, 0)

AddNew.Resize(16, 7).Value = wks.Range("B1:H16").Value
wks.Range("B1:H16").Value = ""

End Sub
```